# Cannot Quit the C# application using Sentinel Value

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have created application that will allow the user to enter numbers which provide the average of the numbers entered. The user will be allowed to enter as many numbers as they choose. After each entry I have display the current average.

I am not able to quit the application. I need help to find some problem in the code.

The Code is below is now corrected:

```
 string input = "";
 double noentered = 0;
 double total=0;
 double average = 0;
 do
 {
Console.Write("enter a number or Q to quit",input);   
input = Console.ReadLine();
if (input != "q" && input != "Q") 
{
 noentered++;
 total +=  Convert.ToInt32(input);
 average = total / noentered;
 Console.WriteLine(" Total: {0} \t Number Entered: {1} \t Average:{2}", total, noentered,average);
}
}
 }while (input != "q" && input != "Q");
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping thru in debugger and see what happens when you enter `q`?

Comment: Yes I did. But nothing is getting printed in variable "noentered"

Comment: If you type "q" or "Q" it exits the screen and Warning shows up "Input String is not in correct format"

Answer (score 1):

Move your if-sentence to check the input before trying to convert it to an int:

```
        string input = "";
        double noentered = 0;
        double total = 0;
        double average = 0;
        do
        {
            {
                Console.Write("enter a number or Q to quit", input);
                input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (input != "q" && input != "Q")
                {
                    total += Convert.ToInt32(input);
                    average = total / noentered;
                    noentered++;
                    Console.WriteLine(" Total: {0} \t Number Entered: {1} \t Average:{2}", total, noentered, average);
                }


            }
        } while (input != "q" && input != "Q");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
      do
        {
            Console.Write("enter a number or Q to quit", input);
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (input != "q" && input != "Q")
            {
                noentered++;
                total += Convert.ToInt32(input);
                average = total / noentered;
                Console.WriteLine(" Total: {0} \t Number Entered: {1} \t Average:{2}", total, noentered, average);
            }
        } while (input != "q" && input != "Q");
```

This works. Please notice the placement of the if condition. The entered value is checked after reading. In your code, the value is checked after one pass. Also, you might want to increment the count before calculating average for getting accurate average value.